# Upload a file via AJAX as soon as the file is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I cannot find this in Google - I want to do the following:-

- A user selects an image from the input type=file option
- The input type=file button disappears as soon as the pic is clicked
- The image is uploaded via AJAX
- When the file is uploaded a text box is shown to enter the description of the image.

Now, I cannot understand how/when to call the AJAX call. Please tell me the jQuery event of user selecting an image , using which I can call the AJAX function.
Thanks in advance...any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The `change` function for `input` elements would be triggered right after a file is selected I believe.

Comment: please elaborate @tymeJV , I will mark your answer as the chosen one...if I find it correct..thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.change` function can fire when a file is selected on your `input`. Take the following sample HTML:

```
<input type='file' id='fileImage'/>
```

Now with jQuery, bind a `change` event to this input:

```
$("#fileImage").change(function() {
    //Here is where you will make your AJAX call
    console.log("Image selected!");
});
```

This will fire immediately after a file has been selected.